# How to fix libssl.lib not found error on Windows 10?

Tags: openssl, msbuild, cryptography

I'm trying to install a python package which is not publicly available. However, the problem here is not with the package but with ms build tools not finding `libssl.lib`. Here's the error I get while it tries to install cryptography. Please note that I had cryptography installed using pip separately, but the package still tries to build and install it.

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\SHREST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpyfoyip74'
       cwd: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tz7xrs6s\cryptography_1a90283ee8854dbc8b5878dca15d28c1
  Complete output (146 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography
  copying src\cryptography\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography
  copying src\cryptography\fernet.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography
  copying src\cryptography\utils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography
  copying src\cryptography\__about__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography
  copying src\cryptography\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\_oid.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\x509
  copying src\cryptography\x509\base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\x509
  copying src\cryptography\x509\certificate_transparency.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\x509
  copying src\cryptography\x509\extensions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\x509
  copying src\cryptography\x509\general_name.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\x509
  copying src\cryptography\x509\name.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\x509
  copying src\cryptography\x509\ocsp.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\x509
  copying src\cryptography\x509\oid.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\x509
  copying src\cryptography\x509\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\x509
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\interfaces.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\bindings
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\bindings
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\cmac.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\constant_time.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\hashes.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\hmac.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\keywrap.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\padding.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\poly1305.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\aead.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\backend.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\ciphers.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\cmac.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\decode_asn1.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\dh.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\dsa.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\ec.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\ed25519.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\ed448.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\encode_asn1.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\hashes.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\hmac.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\ocsp.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\poly1305.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\rsa.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\utils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\x25519.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\x448.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\x509.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\binding.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\_conditional.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\dh.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\dsa.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\ec.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\ed25519.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\ed448.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\padding.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\rsa.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\utils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\x25519.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\x448.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers\aead.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers\algorithms.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers\base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers\modes.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf\concatkdf.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf\hkdf.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf\kbkdf.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf\pbkdf2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf\scrypt.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf\x963kdf.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\kdf
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization\base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization\pkcs12.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization\ssh.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor\hotp.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor\totp.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor\utils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor
  copying src\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\twofactor
  running egg_info
  writing src\cryptography.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src\cryptography.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to src\cryptography.egg-info\requires.txt
  writing top-level names to src\cryptography.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'src\cryptography.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'vectors'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'azure-pipelines.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.azure-pipelines'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.azure-pipelines'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.travis'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'release.py'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'dev-requirements.txt'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'rtd-requirements.txt'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
  writing manifest file 'src\cryptography.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  running build_ext
  generating cffi module 'build\\temp.win32-3.8\\Release\\_padding.c'
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
  generating cffi module 'build\\temp.win32-3.8\\Release\\_constant_time.c'
  generating cffi module 'build\\temp.win32-3.8\\Release\\_openssl.c'
  building '_openssl' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\build
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\build\temp.win32-3.8
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include -Ic:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcbuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\_openssl.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\_openssl.obj
  _openssl.c
  build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\_openssl.c(1509): warning C4098: 'Cryptography_HMAC_CTX_free': 'void' function returning a value
  build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\_openssl.c(12129): warning C4090: 'return': different 'const' qualifiers
  build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\_openssl.c(12140): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\_openssl.c(12155): warning C4090: 'return': different 'const' qualifiers
  build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\_openssl.c(12166): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\_openssl.c(28350): warning C4090: 'return': different 'const' qualifiers
  build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\_openssl.c(28373): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\_openssl.c(40431): warning C4090: 'function': different 'const' qualifiers
  build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\_openssl.c(40469): warning C4090: 'function': different 'const' qualifiers
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\PCbuild\win32 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\lib\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86" libssl.lib libcrypto.lib advapi32.lib crypt32.lib gdi32.lib user32.lib ws2_32.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__openssl build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\_openssl.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\_openssl.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\_openssl.lib /NXCOMPAT /DYNAMICBASE
  LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libssl.lib'
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cryptography
Failed to build cryptography
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cryptography which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I've also included OpenSSL in the environment variables

[image]

However, I keep getting the above error. I also re-installed Visual Studio build tools 2019. Not really sure what else can I try to fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `libpath` MS build tools is using doesn't have `OpenSSL` lib path, so it can't find `libssl.lib`. One possible solution would be to copy `.lib` files from `openssl` directory you showed in the environment variables to Python lib `c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\libs`. It should work.

Comment: Thank you. That is interesting. I did what you suggested, and the error went away, but I have a different error now.  _openssl.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _X509_REQ_get_version
  _openssl.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _BN_rand_range
  build\lib.win32-3.8\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\_openssl.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 855 unresolved externals
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120

Comment: From the env vars you showed above, it seems like you have installed 64-bit version, but your build tools is running 32-bit version. This may be due to the version mismatch. Try installing 32-bit version OpenSSL from https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html. Copy the .lib files from the 32-bit openssl location to python lib folder.

Comment: Wow!! that was it. now it's installed without any problem. Thanks, @Kuni. This is wonderful, thank you for solving this for me. I had been working on it since yesterday.